# Opening a link in new window

Tags: java, selenium

I need to open a link in a new window with Selenium.  I found the following 2 (assume we is the WebElement and I have already found it and myWait just performs a wait for x milliseconds):

1)

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.contextClick(we).perform();
myWait(1000); // allow the menu to come up
act.sendKeys(which).perform();
```

2)

```
we.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

In #1 I see the menu come up, but the `sendKeys` does not work (oh, by the way the "which" in sendKeys is a "t").  In #2 it simply ignores it.

In #1 is the menu that comes up in a new window already?  Do I have to `driver.switchTo()`?  or if not, what am I doing wrong?

Also, is there another way to do this?  we is an element of form `<a href=blah>` and a regular click opens fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to open a link in a new window:

```
Actions newTab= new Actions(driver);
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element"));

//Opening the link in new window
newTab.contextClick(link).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

**Note:** After you've opened the link a new window, **to get control of it, you need to get the handle of this child window, switch to it using `driver.switchTo.window("childwindowhandle")`** and take further actions. And, after that you can close it and switch back to the Parent window(original one) and take actions here **(Make sure to get the parent window handle before you open the link in a new window, so that switching back to it is easier)**.

Comment: It is a bit tricky to get childwindowhandle, right?  I assume there are only 2 windows open.  I go through a loop of window handles.  If the handle does not match my current handle I assume it is the child.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah! that is the way to switch to a child window.